# How to place a background image that can scroll with the page

Tags: background, background-image, watermark

I am trying to place a background image (color) on my page that can scroll with the page, that looks like a watermark, that allows me to still click on objects that land on top of the panel.  I have attempted to make a 'panel' with the code below.  The problem is, when I have a page that needs to scroll, the panel stays in the same place and I would like it to scroll up with the text that it was sitting below.  Also, I am not able to click on any of my object that land on top/below the panel.

```
    #bodyPanel {
      width: 3000px;
      height: 400px;
      border: none;
      background-color: rgba(192, 169, 29, 0.42);
      position: fixed;
      top: 300px;
      left: -275px;
      color: #696969;
     }

        <div id="bodyPanel">
          <div id="body">
             @RenderBody()
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following attributes to your background:

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
```

To test this:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-attachment

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned below use **background-attachment** property. But you will have to use **background-image** instead of **background-color**